# jqGrid without using ajax

Tags: jqgrid

I want to display data in jqGrid without using ajax. I have data in Json array format. The data in the array is 
not getting displayed. It prints only the column names. PFB the code

```
$("#myTable").jqGrid({
            data:  [ 'Jack',  '1000' ] ,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['User Name','Series No'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'User Name',width:55},
                {name:'Series No', width:90}    
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            caption:"JSON Example"
        });
```

Am I missing anything? Please help

Comment: data:  [{'User Name': 'Jack', 'Series No': '1000'} ] ,

Comment: Thanks @guny , I tried it , but still not working. Do I need to add any other parameters?

Comment: remove space for the index and try  data:  [ 'username':'Jack',  'series':'1000' ] ,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['User Name','Series No'],colModel:[
                {name:'username',width:55},
                {name:'series', width:90}    
            ],

Comment: @guny - Tried, but syntax error at data:  [ 'username':'Jack', 'series':'1000' ] ,

Comment: datatype attribute should be "jsonstring" instead of "json"